# Can logarithm bases 2 and 10 both be expressed as $e$ in $\log$ / $\ln$ entropy?

Tags: probability, logarithms, exponential-function, information-theory, entropy

If

$$\exp\left({\sum_x p(x)\log_e \frac{1}{p(x)}}\right) = 2^{-\sum_x p(x)\log_2 p(x)}$$

then does

$$\exp\left({\sum_x p(x)\ln \frac{1}{p(x)}}\right) = 10^{-\sum_x p(x)\ln p(x)}?$$

Finally, can *both* of the above RHS's be expressed as the formula below, with an *e* at the front instead of $10$ or $2$, or only one? *if not both*, which one?

$$e^{-\sum_x p(x)\log_b p(x)}$$

In other words, does
$$e^{-\sum_x p(x)\log p(x)} = 2^{-\sum_x p(x)\log p(x)}$$

and

$$e^{-\sum_x p(x)\ln p(x)} = 10^{-\sum_x p(x)\ln p(x)}?$$

Answer (score 3):

For any base $b$,
$$
    b^{-\sum_x p(x) \log_b p(x)} = \prod_x b^{-p(x) \log_b p(x)} = \prod_x (b^{\log_b p(x)})^{-p(x)} = \prod_x p(x)^{-p(x)}
$$
which does not depend on $b$. So all these expressions are equal.

However, the base of the exponent must match the base of the log.

Comment: i don't see how product operators apply to the question. I just want an answer/confirmation for the last two formulas in the question